# Foreach loop with additional behavior for one specific iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm iterating over a list with a foreach loop and I want to do some additional stuff to exactly one of the `x` that I iterate over (specifically `cryoTemp` in the code below). I could add this  functionality with a simple `if` statement in the body of the loop, but it sets off a subconscious "bad code" alarm in my head, as the `if` statement will be evaluated on every iteration, even though it will only evaluate to true once. Is there a smarter, perhaps more "Pythonic" way to do this?

```
for p in self.params:
    < get parameter p from server >
    < parse response >
    log_in_redis_and_mysql(p, value)

    # log cooling rate based on cryoTemp value
    if p == 'cryoTemp':
        self.pastCryoTemps.append(value)
        # calculate average of queue when it fills up then remove the oldest (first) element
        if (len(self.pastCryoTemps) == 4):
            differences = []
            for i in range(len(self.pastCryoTemps) - 1):
                differences.append(-(self.pastCryoTemps[i] - self.pastCryoTemps[i + 1]))
            average = sum(differences) / len(differences)
            log_in_redis_and_mysql('cooling_rate', average)
            self.pastCryoTemps.pop(0)
```

Comment: Show your `if` statement.

Comment: Give us an idea of the contents of y (in addition to showing your if statement)

Comment: Well, you can always `break` the loop after that one. Still not perfect, though.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that your `if` statement would have any real impact.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  I wouldn't worry about it unless you're trying to speed up slow code, and this is one of the last things I would do.

Comment: Are you doing anything else while iterating? If the goal is to do something to one and one element alone, use [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to find it (and then do whatever you want with it) instead of manually iterating over it.

Comment: @zwer: Yes, the loop retrieves the listed parameters from another server and updates them in our local Redis server and logs the values to MySQL. The if statement would be used to calculate a running average of only one of these values. I didn't want to do these extra steps outside the loop because the value might change between the two gets, or otherwise would result in code duplication.

Comment: @NickSilvestri - Perhaps you could explain your actual problem - chances are that an additional `if` check will not affect the performance at all given that you're working with database connections which are many, many times slower than almost anything you can do with an additional check. Either way, the actual problem/conundrum might help us give you some ideas you haven't considered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which index has the special-cased behavior, you can do:

```
for i, x in enumerate(y):
    if i == known_index:
        g(x)
    else:
        f(x)
```

If you don't, then there's nothing wrong with simply checking each `x` against a predicate.